# Winform keyboard management

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, keyboard-events

I would like to control the focus of my winform application. It is made of a custom listbox and several other component.
I want all the keyboard event be managed by my window handlers in order to avoid specific control key handling (for example when I press a character and the list box is focused, the item starting with the correspondant letter is selected which is not a correct behaviour for my application).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your form's KeyPreview property is set to true.  Then this code should work for canceling your key events to the listbox...

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ActiveControl == listBox1)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

The KeyPress event may not work for all your scenarios.  In that case, I would try out the KeyDown event.

Comment: Will setting e.Handled to true discard the keypress?

Comment: Yes.  Basically, you are telling the event that you handled the key event and you don't want it to do anything with it.

Comment: In fact I used KeyDown which handle the both following case:
- When typing character the list item are not selected.
- When hitting the Up/Down arrow the list item selection does'nt change
Please edit your answer so I mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hmmm.  What version of the framework/visual studio are you using?  Handling KeyDown only works for the up/down arrows for me.  I have to handle the KeyPress if I don't want letters to select listbox items.  Are you using the out-of-the-box listbox control?